# Function returning blank array in inspect element with inaccessible data inside

Tags: javascript

**SCENARIO**
So I am trying to do multiple API requests with different URLs, add all the responses to an array, then return the array and use it. My code:

```
const getData = (dataURLs) => {
  let returnData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < dataURLs.length; i++) {
    getFetch(dataURLs[i]).then((response) => {
      returnData.push(response);
      return response;
    });
  }
  console.log(returnData[0]);
  return returnData;
};
```

So this is the function that makes the requests, here is what the `getFetch` function is:

```
const getFetch = async (url) => {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        // get error message from body or default to response status
        const error = (response && response.message) || response.status;
        return error;
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
};
```

This just makes the request and returns the JSON which is what I want, and this function works as I use it in other places.

**PROBLEM**

My issue is, when i make the request using the `getData` function, it will return a blank array '`[]`', however when I click on this array in inspect element, it displays this.

```
[] ->
    0: {nodes: Array(5), edges: Array(5), self: Array(1)}
    length: 1
```

If I try to access anything in this array in js it just doesn't let me. But if I look at it in Inspect Element, it will be a blank array that I can expand and it displays the requested data inside it

Just wondering if anyone knew a fix to this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into here is that the function returns the array before the promises have resolved (and put the data that you want into the arrays). You will need to wait for the promises first. There are a few ways you can do this, but one way is to put the promises into the array and use a [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get all of the values when they are available.

```
const getData = (dataURLs) => {
  let returnPromises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < dataURLs.length; i++) {
    returnPromises.push(getFetch(dataURLs[i]));
  }

  return Promise.all(returnPromises);
};
```

From here on you will continue to use this function's result as a promise.

```
getData([...]).then(([result1, result2, ...resultN]) => {...})
```

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "getData([...]).then(([result1, result2, ...resultN]) => {...})". How would I access the data once the promise has been resolved and returned in the "return Promise.all(returnPromises)"?

Comment: For the `getData` edit I supplied, the order that you put the URLs in decides the order the promise results come back in.

`getData([url1, url2, ...urlN]).then((response1, response2, ...responseN) => { ... });`

The `Promise.all()` takes an array of promises and waits for the result of each.